# d3 - Get pixel width between two numbers on line chart x-axis (to set a background <rect> width)

Tags: d3.js

I have a basic line chart implemented with axes defined like so:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([300, 1600]).range([0, w]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([100, 0]).range([0, h]);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient('left')
.ticks(10);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient('bottom')
.ticks(16);
```

Now I want to have a `rect` filled with a linear gradient display behind the line chart's `path`. I want the `rect`'s height to be the full height on the y-axis, and I want the width to match the width of the chart between 300 (x-axis start) and some number `N` on the x-axis.

I'm not sure where to start. Something tells me I need to get d3 to tell me the width in pixels between 300 and N on the x-axis, and set that as my `rect` width, but I don't know how to get that information. I want a dynamic solution so I can make the chart scalable.

Any pointing in the right direction is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have your domains properly set, that's all you need to position your rectangle.

For instance, using the code below (almost exactly your code), let's position a rectangle starting at 300 in x scale and going to 1200, and starting at 10 in y scale and going to 40:

```
var myRectangle = svg.append("rect")
   .attr("x", x(300))
   .attr("y", y(40))
   .attr("width", x(1200) - x(300))
   .attr("height", y(10) - y(40))
   .attr("fill", "teal");
```

So, to position the rectangle at 300 in the x scale we just need `x(300)`. to calculate the width, we just need a subtraction: `x(1200) - x(300)`.

In the y scale things are trickier, because the y scale here (notice that I inverted your y scale range) is the *normal* scale in math, with the zero at the bottom. But in SVG coordinates system the zero is at the top, not at the bottom. So, the origin is `y(40)`, but the height is `y(10) - y(40)`.

But for the full height the math is easier:

```
.attr("y", y(100))
.attr("height", y(0) - y(100))
```

Check the snippet (height being the full height of y axis):

```js
var w = 400, h = 400;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([300, 1600]).range([30, w - 20]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([100, 0]).range([20, h - 20]);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient('left')
.ticks(10);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient('bottom')
.ticks(5);

var myRectangle = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", x(300))
  .attr("y", y(100))
  .attr("width", x(1200) - x(300))
  .attr("height", y(0) - y(100))
  .attr("fill", "teal");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - 20) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(30,0)")
  .call(yAxis);
```

```css
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #aaa;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```